# ZF1: Url view helper look for scheme in routes

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible in ZF1 to define/force the scheme (http or https) for routes?
So that the url view helper automaticly enforces that scheme when building the url.

I already have a forceHttps feature in my controllers, where each action can be redirected to https.
But this results in additional redirects.

I know that the url view helper don't supply the full url, and that the serverUrl view helper is used for that.

Is there a way to extend the url view helper and access the settings in the route specifications, so the view helper "fallback" to serverUrl, if scheme is specified for route.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an absolute URL you will have to use serverUrl view helper in combination with url view helper

```
$this->getHelper('ServerUrl')->setScheme('https');
$this->serverUrl() . $this->url(array('action'=>'index'));
```

Comment: I know that. I'm asking if its possible to extend `$this->url(array(), 'aRandomRoute');` so the url view helper looks into the settings for the specified route, if the route is specified as HTTPS, then return the absolute URL by utilizing the ServerUrl viewhelper.